# CAB project targetting only Windows Mobile 6.1 or 6.5.3 devices - Way to restrict the install?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, cab

I was looking to create a CAB project in Visual Studio 2008 in order to deploy an application to several Windows Mobile devices. Among those devices, some of them are running Windows Mobile **6.1**, others Windows Mobile **6.5** and the last ones Windows Mobile **6.5.3**.

I want to restrict the possibility to install my CAB to the 6.1 & 6.5.3 terminals, not the 6.5 ones.

I already used in the past CAB projects and so I looked at the property window of my project in order to see if I can set the OS minimum/maximal version or if there was a field to excluse some OS versions. The fields are described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228717%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Especially:

> **OSVersionMax**
>
> Specifies the maximum Windows CE operating system version number on
>   which the .cab file can be installed. There are several ways to
>   determine the operating system version number of a device:
>
> - See Operating System Version of Windows Mobile Devices.
> - View the About page on the device.
> - Programmatically query the device by using OSMajor and OSMinor.
>
> **OSVersionMin**
>
> Specifies the minimum Windows CE operating system version number on
>   which the .cab file can be installed. There are several ways to
>   determine the operating system version number of a device:
>
> - See Operating System Version of Windows Mobile Devices.
> - View the About page on the device.
> - Programmatically query the device by using OSMajor and OSMinor.

The versions of the OS are based on Windows CE version (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722874%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Windows Mobile 6.5.3 ==> 5.2.23090
>
> Windows Mobile 6.5 ==> 5.2.21234
>
> Windows Mobile 6.1.4 ==> 5.2.20757
>
> Windows Mobile 6.1 ==> 5.2.19202

I can't any solution to generate only 1 CAB compatible with my 6.1 & 6.5.3 but not 6.5.

It seems that I should do 2 CAB, each targeting one version. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `setup.dll` that does the OS version check before installation.

[MSDN Documentation is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) (though they seem to move links all the time).
[Another example of the code is here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/wince-winmobile-setupdll.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks Chris, I did not know this part of CAB deployment! I read that there is no problem to include the DLL if the CAB is made through Visual Studio, using properties, cool. But I got to find the way to check the OS Version in C++, as it seems mandatory that this setup is made in C++, right?

Comment: Probably `GetVersionEx` or `SystemParametersInfo` with `SPI_GETPLATFORMVERSION` and yes, this must be done in C.